# Nextjs state reset every socket event occur

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, next.js

I tried to make chat functionality which will integrated to my Nextjs app. I followed documentation, but chat log reset every single socket event occurs.
Code is as below:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import io from 'socket.io-client'

export default function Chat() {

    const [chats, setChats] = useState([])
    let socket = io(':3000')
    
    useEffect(() => {

        socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
    
            console.log(chats)
            setChats([
                ...chats,
                msg
            ]) 
            window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);  
        }.bind(this));

    }, [])

    const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        let input = document.getElementById('input');
        if (input.value) {      
            socket.emit('chat message client', input.value);
            input.value = '';    
        }
    }
    
    console.log(chats)

    return (
        <div className='container mt-5 pt-5'>
            <ul id="messages">
                {
                    chats.map(chat => <li>{chat}</li>)
                }
            </ul>    
            <form id="form" onSubmit={submitHandler}>      
                <input id="input" autocomplete="off" />
                <button>Send</button>    
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

express chat server:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require("cors");
const socket = require("socket.io");

const app = express();

app.use(cors())

const server = app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

const io = socket(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:5000",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
        allowedHeaders: ["my-custom-header"],
        credentials: true
    }
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log("connected")
    socket.on('chat message client', (msg) => {
        console.log('message: ' + msg);
        io.emit('chat message', msg)
    });
});
```

state 'chats' only contain latest message since chats set to empty array every time.

I tried to change useEffect hook runs every chats changed as below:

```
useEffect(() => {

        socket.off('chat message').on('chat message', function(msg) {
    
            console.log(chats)
            setChats([
                ...chats,
                msg
            ]) 
            window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);  
        }.bind(this));

    }, [chats])
```

It works around 10 times but after that it shows web socket connection failed error
[image]
It seems like chat functionality make socket connection every single time. (That's why I'm
trying to add .off('chat message'), seem like not working properly though).
I have no idea how it fixed.
Please advise me of any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem may occur because you are initializing socket variable at every render when setting new state with "setChat" function.

try to move variable outside component for example:

```
let socket = null

export default function Chat() {

const [chats, setChats] = useState([])    

useEffect(() => {
    if(socket == null)// Ensure that this variable is not initialized
        socket = io(':3000')
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {

        console.log(chats)
        setChats([
            ...chats,
            msg
        ]) 
        window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);  
    }.bind(this));

    }, [])
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I made some tweak to your code.

Comment: You are welcome bro, feel free to modify it as you wish :)

Answer (score 0):

I made some tweak to @humam ayad's code:

```
let socket = null

export default function Chat() {

    const [chats, setChats] = useState([])
    
    useEffect(() => {

        if(socket == null) socket = io(':3000')

        socket.off('chat message').on('chat message', function(msg) {
    
            console.log(chats)
            setChats([
                ...chats,
                msg
            ]) 
            window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);  
        }.bind(this));

    }, [chats])
```